# Merge two tables on one key where the date is closest and on another key where the value lies in any two columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, python-datetime

I have two tables df1 that looks like:

```
| DATE      | NAME           | TEAM     |

| 2014-05-02| Mo Salah       | Liverpool|
```

and df2 that looks like:

```
|GameKey| Game_Date | Home_Team      | Away_Team  |

|1      | 2014-08-03| Liverpool      | Brighton   |
```

How can I merge them in such a way  that df1.TEAM is in one of df2.Home_Team or df2.Away_Team and df1.DATE gives me the closest forward match to df2.Game_Date. I'm familiar with merge_asof and can use that to do a forward match on the dates but not entirely sure on how to combine that with the team names merge.

Comment: Please include expected output

Comment: It should just be df2 with the NAME column from df1 since the merge is on the date and team name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same column names if you want to do merge.

Changing df2 Home_Team to TEAM

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"Home_Team": "TEAM"})
```

After that, merge df1 to df2 on TEAM

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on="TEAM", suffixes=('', '_DROP'), how='left')
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I am trying to merge df1['TEAM'] with df2 on 'Home_Team' or 'Visit_Team'

Comment: the concept still the same though...

df1 = df1.rename(columns={"TEAM": "Home_Team"})

new_df = df2.merge(df1, on="TEAM", suffixes=('', '_DROP'), how='left')

Comment: You don't need to have the same column name. You can do left_on and right_on and specify the column name. I suggest you read the documentation.